# Impact of Website Redesign on Google Analytics

Tags: google, statistics

I just finished a redesign for a website that is currently using Google Analytics. I want to continue to use Google Analytics, but I'm not sure if I should create a new profile for the new site or simply use the old UA number.

The new website has a completely different URL structure and much of the content has been updated/deleted/added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a choice you have to make. Google analytics tracks pages by both page title and url. Depending on how you are viewing the report, your new pages with the same page titles will still aggregate together (so the data will combine), whereas when viewing by page url (if the urls have been moved) will show up with new entries (and the data will start over). When viewing the content overlay reports however you will get some odd data because your content has changed.

I personally would just use the same UA number. This will also allow you to easily compare the performance of the new site vs. the old by comparing the data range moving forward to the date range before the site was redesigned. I have done this with a site and it worked well for tracking performance changes.

You should also consider the SEO impacts of making drastic changes to your site. That is a whole other issue altogether.

Comment: Thanks. Any info you can provide on the SEO issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Use 301 redirects for any pages you are moving to a new location. This will allow any inbound link juice to transfer to the new pages. Try to avoid changing your page titles if possible (or as little as possible). The most you change your content, the more you can expect to see a drop in rankings. They should bounce back eventually, but can often take several months.